# Angular 2 - Create a nested JSON object

Tags: json, typescript, angular

I am working on an Angular 2 project that requires me to create a user with address details as shown below

```
{ "address": {
"addition": null,
"city": "Eindhoven",
"housenumber": 12,
"street": "Streetname"},
"email": "a@b.com",
"password": "",
"username": "YourName"}
```

When I GET a user object, the example above is the result. To POST a user object to the back end, I need to create JSON with the same structure.

I am able to display the details of this JSON file when I recieve it. I created two classes:

```
import {Address} from "./Address";
/**
 * Created by Adjoa on 6/14/2016.
 */
export class User {
    name:string;
    username:string;
    email:string;
    address:Address;



    constructor(name:string, username:string, email:string, address:Address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public static createEmptyUser():User{
        return new User("","","",null);
    }
}
```

I need help creating a user that has an address before I send it to the API.

Comment: Well, pass an address instead of null to the User constructor. What's the concrete problem?

Comment: Hey, you should have edited your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814716/angular-2-write-a-nested-json-object) instead of deleting and reposting it with a slight modification.

Comment: If you want to use forms for that: Check out: https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form

Answer (score 0):

If you define

```
usermodel = new User('','','',Address)
```

outside `'createEmptyUser'` and just return

```
JSON.stringify(this.usermodel)
```

inside of it, the JSON will come up in its shape.

Comment: thank you. But could you please explain a little bit further?

Comment: import {Address} from "./Address";
/**
 * Created by Adjoa on 6/14/2016.
 */
export class User {
    name:string;
    username:string;
    email:string;
    address:Address;



    constructor(name:string, username:string, email:string, address:Address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.address = address;
    }
    usermodel = new User('','','',Address);                                                 public static createEmptyUser():User{
        return JSON.stringify(this.usermodel);
    }
}

Comment: It works if the new user has the form for submission: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

Comment: When I use your code, 

this.usermodel doesn't seem to me declared. But it was declared.

Comment: I also get an error EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at new User (http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/User.ts!transpiled:13:30)
    at new User (http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/User.ts!transpiled:14:38)
 
    
ERROR CONTEXT:
[object Object]

Comment: new User(...) depends on import {Address} from "./Address" and I do not have access to that code to discuss further about. If you upload something on plunk or anywhere else, I can see if I can be helpful...